# connect Karate with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, bdd, karate

I would like to use karate and selenium together. I have read how to call "JavaApiTest class" . To get "JavaApiTest"class working, I added karate -core dependency. If I try to run my tests from cucumber runner then I get the 
following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner.(Ljava/lang/Class;)V,

So probably the Cucumber runner has conflict with this dependency, if I remove this dependency than CucumberRunner.runFeature and CucumberRunner.runClasspathFeature miss the corresponding jar files.

I have also another question:
How can I run cucumber and karate features at the same time so that the results are summarized in one report.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix Cucumber and Karate like this, refer this issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/398

If you are having library conflicts, and you think this is a Karate issue, please follow these instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue